# How can I fix these errors during Talend Open Studio installation?

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, openjdk

I'm trying to install [Talend Open Studio](https://www.talend.com/talend-open-studio/) on Ubuntu 16.04 Server, but I got the following errors while trying to run `./TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86.sh`:

```
TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64: Cannot open display:
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.initWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:83)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:208)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/talend/osgi/configurator/OsgiLoaderActivator : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.startExtensionActivator(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.startExtensionActivators(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
        ... 17 more
TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64: Cannot open display:
TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64:
An error has occurred. See the log file
null.
```

---

The Java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

I've also tried Java 8. I've downloaded XULRunner 1.9.2.

Comment: It seems that it needs display (local or remote Xserver). Did you tried to launch it from `ssh -X`?

Comment: why should i use ssh -X?? while i'm connecting to my server through ssh? sorry but i'm beginner :)

Comment: "ssh -X" will render window from server to your client.

Answer (score 0):

The line

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/talend/osgi/configurator/OsgiLoaderActivator : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0

is saying this code was compiled with Java 8. Java 7 cannot run code compiled for Java 8. So you need to install Java 8 to run this.